# can't accept new chunks because there are still 1 deletes from previous migration

Tags: mongodb, sharding, chunks

I have a mongodb production cluster running in 2.6.11 with 20 replicatSets. I getting space disk issue, because the chunks majority are store in one replicatSet. When I check the log, I can see that move chunk failed because of "deletes from previous migration"

> 2015-12-28T17:13:32.164+0000 [conn6504] about to log metadata event: { _id: "db1-2015-12-28T17:13:32-56816dbc6b0464b0a5801db8", server: "db1", clientAddr: "xx.xx.xx.11:50077", time: new Date(1451322812164), what: "moveChunk.start", ns: "emailing_nQafExtB.reports", details: { min: { email: "xxxxxxx" }, max: { email: "xxxxxxx" }, from: "shard16", to: "shard22" } }
>   2015-12-28T17:13:32.675+0000 [conn6504] about to log metadata event: { _id: "db1-2015-12-28T17:13:32-56816dbc6b0464b0a5801db9", server: "db1", clientAddr: "xx.xx.xx.11:50077", time: new Date(1451322812675), what: "moveChunk.from", ns: "emailing_nQafExtB.reports", details: { min: { email: "xxxxxxx" }, max: { email: "xxxxxxx" }, step 1 of 6: 3, step 2 of 6: 314, note: "aborted", errmsg: "moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because  there are still 1 deletes from previous migration" } }

I follow the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640861/movechunk-failed-to-engage-to-shard-in-the-data-transfer-cant-accept-new-chunk), but doesn't work for me. I run stepDown command on one primary and all my cluster primary. I do the same with the cleanUpOrphaned command.

Does somedody run over this problem ?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Do you use noTimeout cursors? If yes and these cursors are not closed they can block deletion of data post migration.

Comment: It was the original problem. We see this and fix it ( we add timeout option in our code ). After this fix, I have done a stepDown on all the primary. The deletes number decrease, but look like some still lock.

Comment: I double check on each primary log file, cleanUpOrphaned command delete none documents:

conn206432] rangeDeleter deleted 0 documents for emailing_nQafExtB.reports from { email: MinKey } -> ....

Comment: Are the chunk migrations occurring now? If not you can run db.currentOp() on each of the primaries to look for blocking operations.

Comment: No, the chunk migration still lock, but when I check the current op they are no activity on this db.

Comment: @ChristopheBiguereau Did you find a solution to this?